# HTMX form submission produces a duplicate form

Tags: django, htmx

[image]

```
{% extends "IntakeApp/base3.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block heading %}
<h2>Allergies for {{request.session.report_claimant}}</h2>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form hx-post="{% url 'allergy' %}" hx-target="#allergy_target" hx-swap="outerHTML">{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form.allergen|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="med-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Allergen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="allergy_target">
            {% for allergy in allergy_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{allergy.allergen}}</td>
                <td>
                    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'allergy-delete' allergy.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
                        <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" value="Delete">
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


{% endblock %}

class AllergyCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Allergy
    template_name = 'IntakeApp/allergy_form.html' 
    form_class = AllergyForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.assessment = Assessment.objects.get(id=self.request.session['assessment_id'])
        return super(AllergyCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy("allergy")

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        assessment_id = self.request.session['assessment_id']
        allergy_list = Allergy.objects.filter(assessment=assessment_id)
        context["allergy_list"] = allergy_list
        return context
```

I tried to all the different hx-swap options, but none fix it...It does post correctly and the swap does work, just not sure why I am getting another form in there. Please help

I added the View above. I think thats were my issue is...not sure if I am supposed to be doing this way or not?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to render the same html content in your view, which instead should only take a specific element.

You can try to use `hx-select="#allergy_target"` so htmx will only fetch the table content.

Comment: Please check my View. I think thats where I have an issue. I am new to this HTMX thing...may not be using it right. Any feedback will much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the hx-select solution? If it didn't work then other way is to render different template (consisting of table only). You can overiide it easily in CBV. My adivice is to switch into FBV. It's much easier to write backend logic when dealing with htmx.

Answer (score 0):

After htmx sends a POST request, your view returns the entire template. What you want is, that your view returns only the html that replaces the `<tbody id="allergy_target">` when a POST request is returned. Therefore, you should write a view, that checks for the request (i.e. POST or GET) and returns the full html when a GET request is received, but only the html snippet, when a POST-request is received. I think something like the following should work (compare [this](https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/htmx-active-search-not-accepting-post-method/17535) post and [this](https://www.rockandnull.com/htmx-django/) blog entry):

P.S.: I would make the login required for medical data. Therefore, I added `@login_required`.

**view.py:**

```
@login_required # I would make the login required for medical data.
def documentation_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST": # Check for POST method
        assessment_id = request.POST.get("assessment_id", None)
        template = "IntakeApp/allergy_form_result.html"
        if assessment_id:
            allergy_list = Allergy.objects.filter(assessment=assessment_id).all()
        else:
            allergy_list = None
    else:
        allergy_list = None
        template = "IntakeApp/allergy_form.html"
    return render(
        request=request,
        template_name=template,
        context={
            "allergy_list": allergy_list
        }
    )
```

**allergy_form.html:**

```
{% block content %}
<form hx-post="{% url 'allergy' %}" hx-target="#allergy_target" hx-swap="outerHTML">{% csrf_token %}

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-0">
            {{ form.allergen|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
</form>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="med-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Allergen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="allergy_target"></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**allergy_form_result.html:**

```
{% for allergy in allergy_list %}
<tr>
    <td>{{allergy.allergen}}</td>
    <td>
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'allergy-delete' allergy.id %}">{% csrf_token %}
            <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" value="Delete">
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Additionally, you could use two seperate view functions: one for the main view, and one for the tabe content. In this case, the hx-post would be something like hx-post="{% url 'allergy-table-content' %} for a view with the name allergy-table-content (as specified in urls.py).